# BeautifulSoup: how to get everything inside <a> tag?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

**SOLVED BY @Barry the Platipus** (see solution at the end)

I am trying to get "Apertura" from the following HTML:

[HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q8Jab.png)

I can't seem to get anything. I have been looking for a while and understand that a  tag has no attribute "cmp-ltrk". So I have tried to get the  above and then try to access the "cmp-ltrk" from there but I am just not succeeding.

What should I do?

This is my code when I try to get the "cmp-ltrk" directly from the "a" tag:

```
url = "https://www.eldiario.es/"

response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")

a_tags = soup.find_all("a")

for i in a_tags:
    print(i)
```

Which gives me:

```
<a class="item" href="https://www.eldiario.es/sociedad/educacion-no-recuperarse-recortes-pp-impuso-decreto-decada_1_9559396.html">
            Educación
        </a>
```

And this is the code when trying from the "h2":

```
url = "https://www.eldiario.es/"

response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")

a_tags = soup.find_all("h2", {"class": "ni-title"})

for i in a_tags:
    print(i)
```

I get something like:

```
<h2 class="ni-title bold"><a href="/sociedad/educacion-no-recuperarse-recortes-pp-impuso-decreto-decada_1_9559396.html">La Educación no consigue recuperarse de los recortes que el PP impuso por decreto hace una década</a></h2>
```

But then I never see the "cmp-ltrk" I am looking for and don't know how to access it.

Note that in both loops I have tried literally every single method for i (i.text, i.next, etc)

Thank you in advance.

---

**SOLUTION**

"Attributes like cmp-ltrk are added dynamically by javascript, once page loads. Requests cannot see them. You need playwright/selenium for this task (less complex solution), or you can go for a js2py solution (more complex). – Barry the Platipus"

This code worked:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["seccion","titulo","link","cmp"])

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)

url = "https://www.eldiario.es/"
driver.get(url)

page_source = driver.page_source

soup = BeautifulSoup(page_source, "lxml")

tags = soup.find_all("h2", {"class": "ni-title"})    

for i in tags:
    l=[]

    i.a["href"]
    cmp = i.a["cmp-ltrk"]
    href = i.a["href"]

    if href.startswith("http"):
        link = href
    else:
        link = "https://www.eldiario.es{0}".format(i.a["href"])

    titulo = i.text
    seccion = i.a["href"].split("/")[1]   
    l.append([seccion,titulo,link,cmp])
    df_ = pd.DataFrame(l,columns=["seccion","titulo","link","cmp"])
    df = pd.concat([df,df_],axis=0)
```

Comment: Use `i.text` accessor.

Comment: I have tried that too, I get the text but not the "Apertura" in the "cmp-ltrk". To be precise in this example I get: 

"La Educación no consigue recuperarse de los recortes que el PP impuso por decreto hace una década" (in the <h2> loop)

And in the <a> loop I get: "Educación"

Comment: Attributes like `cmp-ltrk` are added dynamically by javascript, once page loads. Requests cannot see them. You need playwright/selenium for this task (less complex solution), or you can go for a `js2py` solution (more complex).

Comment: But it happens even after the page is loaded in the browser using console @BarrythePlatipus

Comment: What happens, @Vishnudev? I don't understand what you mean

Comment: Thanks @BarrythePlatipus , this worked. I can get the "cmp-ltrk" **BUT** the content is different from what I see in the sourse code. For instance, when I do it with selenium and bs4 together I get ***cmp-ltrk="hoy-hablamos-de"*** instead of ***cmp-ltrk="Apertura"*** which definitely what is in the source code for this a tag.

Comment: If JS dynamically creates them, you should be able to access the elements after JS creates them. But, even then it only returns one element in the Browser console. `document.querySelector("[cmp-ltrk]");` @BarrythePlatipus

Comment: @BarrythePlatipus it works when I soup.find_all("h2", {"class": "ni-title"}). Thanks!!!

Comment: @AdriánSánchezdelaSierra check my updated answer: it's a way of getting all links from that page, with their respective cmp_ltrk_attribute.

Comment: @Vishnudev you want to do `document.querySelectorAll("[cmp-ltrk]");` in browser's console, to get all links.

Comment: Yeah! Missed that. Makes sense @BarrythePlatipus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is a workaround to get all links with their respective `cmp-ltrk` attribute:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)
big_list = []
url = "https://www.eldiario.es/"

headers = {
    'User-Agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
    }

def has_specific_attr(tag):
    return tag.has_attr('data-mrf-recirculation')

r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = bs(r.text, 'html.parser')
all_elems_with_attrs = soup.find_all(has_specific_attr)
for x in all_elems_with_attrs:
    cmp_ltrk_attribute = x.get('data-mrf-recirculation')
    urls = x.select('a')
    for url in urls:
        big_list.append((cmp_ltrk_attribute, url.get_text(strip=True), url.get('href')))
df = pd.DataFrame(big_list, columns = ['CMP-LTRK', 'Title', 'Link'])
print(df)
```

Result in terminal:

```
    CMP-LTRK    Title   Link
0   hoy-hablamos-de Educación   https://www.eldiario.es/sociedad/educacion-no-recuperarse-recortes-pp-impuso-decreto-decada_1_9559396.html
1   hoy-hablamos-de Rebajas fiscales    https://www.eldiario.es/economia/rebajas-fiscales-evidencian-ideologia-impuestos-derecha-favorece-ricos-izquierda-trabajadores_1_9583778.html
2   hoy-hablamos-de Feijóo  https://www.eldiario.es/internacional/ultima-hora-invasion-rusa-https://www.eldiario.es/politica/feijoo-cobija-bipartidismo-elite-empresarial-ofensiva-fiscal-sanchez_129_9587317.html-directo-1-de-octubre_6_9586346_1094209.html
3   hoy-hablamos-de Lula da Silva   https://www.eldiario.es/internacional/lula-enfrenta-bolsonaro-duelo-historico-brasil_1_9567743.html
4   hoy-hablamos-de Liz Truss   https://www.eldiario.es/politica/ansia-reducir-impuestos-liz-truss-hunda-economia-britanica-dias_129_9583720.html
... ... ... ...
677 Navegamos-con       https://www.yorokobu.es/monotasking/
678 Navegamos-con   Monotasking, la revolución de hacer una sola cosa a la vez  https://www.yorokobu.es/monotasking/
679 Navegamos-con       /responsables/
680 Navegamos-con       https://www.eldiario.es/responsables/ventajas-darse-alta-autonomo-discapacidad_1_9160670.html
681 Navegamos-con   Estas son las ventajas de darse de alta de autónomo con discapacidad    https://www.eldiario.es/responsables/ventajas-darse-alta-autonomo-discapacidad_1_9160670.html
682 rows × 3 columns
```

​The solution is based on inspecting the page loaded without Javascript, and searching for term `Apertura`: the only element with such attribute value is a div - attribute being `data-mrf-recirculation`. The assumption was that all links in that div will be enriched with `cmp-ltrk="<the data-mrf-recirculation value of the parent element>"`.

Comment: Actually, the CMP-LTRK I get with your code is "hoy-hablamos-de", instead of "Apertura", I can't figure why.

Comment: @AdriánSánchezdelaSierra, you get *ALL* the links from that page, with *ALL* their cmp-ltrk  attributes. It's a matter of filtering the dataframe for 'Apertura' value in CMP_LTRK column: `print(df[df['CMP-LTRK'] == 'Apertura'])`